# Most Recent Event - WHERE Subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I have to extract the **most recent** event, of a specified type (y), for each distinct account while pulling a company name from a transaction number contained in a substring.

So far I've had a go at it and managed to get a result that gave me all the unique transactions times, for event y, for each account. But I've not managed to get just the **most recent** one.

This code only gives the **single** most recent timestamp rather than the most recent timestamp for each account.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    SELECT 
      tbl1.account_id, 
      tbl2.company_name 
    FROM tbl1
      INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.company_id = SUBSTRING(x) --Substring from tbl1
    WHERE 
      tbl1.event_timestamp = (
        SELECT 
          MAX(tbl1.event_timestamp) 
        FROM 
          tbl1
        WHERE 
          tbl1.event_type = 'y'
      ) 
    GROUP BY 
      tbl1.account_id, 
      tbl2.company_name, 
      tbl1.event_type
```

As requested I've provided some fake data to work with

**Tbl1**

```
account_id  event_timestamp event_type  event_value
044ad628-7a859842851    45:19.2 Other1  RandomString
044ad628-7a859842851    32:33.2 Other1  RandomString
04a91508-c4180d4b1af    20:24.0 Other1  RandomString
04a91508-c4180d4b1af    17:21.3 Other1  RandomString
04a91508-c4180d4b1af    26:53.1 Other1  RandomString
05070c61-15e06fcb45f    53:25.8 Other1  RandomString
05070c61-15e06fcb45f    22:59.0 Other1  RandomString
05e1c63e-60d80bec44a    28:14.1 Other1  RandomString
05e1c63e-60d80bec44a    09:17.5 Other1  RandomString
072a211e-e392b853757    26:21.5 Other1  RandomString
072a211e-e392b853757    37:53.0 Other1  RandomString
0d8219ed-31077dfc7ea    16:29.9 Other1  RandomString
044ad628-7a859842851    50:22.4 Other2  
04a91508-c4180d4b1af    27:03.5 Other2  
05070c61-15e06fcb45f    53:28.0 Other2  
05e1c63e-60d80bec44a    27:42.7 Other2  
072a211e-e392b853757    27:24.8 Other2  
0d8219ed-31077dfc7ea    25:13.1 Other2  
0ed9210e-8146094d589    19:57.3 Other2  
20f56fe9-ed325ee400d    23:34.8 Other2  
0d8219ed-31077dfc7ea    06:02.6 y   le6ybpg9-hhzk-74y-og5cw6-9b4g6upxap
0d8219ed-31077dfc7ea    23:35.2 y   r9htzaho-i1lv-w22-fd4xfg-mgwubrqmgp
0ed9210e-8146094d589    41:33.7 y   ns3oir3h-peap-kbm-akp8uw-n9ogl1gzu8
0ed9210e-8146094d589    19:47.4 y   hpzxuxdv-5981-04v-mblpvp-k2c233687b
20f56fe9-ed325ee400d    58:02.6 y   pwpzncqn-irop-n6d-hkvcn8-5t9jrmbopp
20f56fe9-ed325ee400d    03:39.7 y   le6ybpg9-hhzk-74y-og5cw6-9b4g6upxap
044ad628-7a859842851    45:51.6 y   ns3oir3h-peap-kbm-akp8uw-n9ogl1gzu8
044ad628-7a859842851    05:14.8 y   r9htzaho-i1lv-w22-fd4xfg-mgwubrqmgp
04a91508-c4180d4b1af    23:56.5 y   m25ytyr3-om10-tq6-sxhl1l-owl6cxempd
04a91508-c4180d4b1af    23:23.9 y   lrdesglo-moq1-p2o-3d1ua9-c2lcgzixf6
04a91508-c4180d4b1af    26:16.8 y   hpzxuxdv-5981-04v-mblpvp-k2c233687b
05070c61-15e06fcb45f    59:32.5 y   h9bsdsf4-8852-6iw-qovigp-99ci5veu1o
05070c61-15e06fcb45f    25:58.6 y   avktf3bx-cexh-jxg-zo20fp-dhhvdh6ej2
05070c61-15e06fcb45f    14:53.6 y   5y26f61j-q5dh-dwg-ww2gl1-bmbx9n5e69
05070c61-15e06fcb45f    25:32.5 y   0tco3qcl-u86o-klp-tk11rv-rluv1qocm9
05070c61-15e06fcb45f    51:38.7 y   avktf3bx-cexh-jxg-zo20fp-dhhvdh6ej2
05e1c63e-60d80bec44a    09:36.2 y   avktf3bx-cexh-jxg-zo20fp-dhhvdh6ej2
072a211e-e392b853757    49:06.0 y   lrdesglo-moq1-p2o-3d1ua9-c2lcgzixf6
0d8219ed-31077dfc7ea    04:21.5 y   49e8tqjf-6mf5-v79-v3c7m5-uq9vj7jep7
0d8219ed-31077dfc7ea    14:51.3 y   2vzu5b4z-o1vl-yre-s6he7w-qoomy7waup
0ed9210e-8146094d589    29:22.4 y   wa87pywz-lhnr-xwu-shcefz-55dcippg00
0ed9210e-8146094d589    52:32.7 y   hpzxuxdv-5981-04v-mblpvp-k2c233687b
20f56fe9-ed325ee400d    06:57.2 y   ns3oir3h-peap-kbm-akp8uw-n9ogl1gzu8
20f56fe9-ed325ee400d    04:10.8 y   49e8tqjf-6mf5-v79-v3c7m5-uq9vj7jep7
```

**tbl2**

```
company_id  company_name 
xqeprsg1-hey6-lc6-ih6oqj-m5shlez0vz Company 1
pb39s8hv-6qf2-ggz-j6x8zg-zwj6q112q5 Company 2
hpzxuxdv-5981-04v-mblpvp-k2c233687b Company 3
lrdesglo-moq1-p2o-3d1ua9-c2lcgzixf6 Company 4
r9htzaho-i1lv-w22-fd4xfg-mgwubrqmgp Company 5
pwpzncqn-irop-n6d-hkvcn8-5t9jrmbopp Company 6
49e8tqjf-6mf5-v79-v3c7m5-uq9vj7jep7 Company 7
k7dj8rco-5gn2-mgd-f9un5v-4cr74xr4tg Company 8
52n1pen7-g89c-fod-gcb70e-lhlojv6rot Company 9
5y26f61j-q5dh-dwg-ww2gl1-bmbx9n5e69 Company 10
x4jlwbzl-apmb-fql-vu1ske-69a3q55h1y Company 11
m25ytyr3-om10-tq6-sxhl1l-owl6cxempd Company 12
2vzu5b4z-o1vl-yre-s6he7w-qoomy7waup Company 13
ns3oir3h-peap-kbm-akp8uw-n9ogl1gzu8 Company 14
0tco3qcl-u86o-klp-tk11rv-rluv1qocm9 Company 15
le6ybpg9-hhzk-74y-og5cw6-9b4g6upxap Company 16
wa87pywz-lhnr-xwu-shcefz-55dcippg00 Company 17
avktf3bx-cexh-jxg-zo20fp-dhhvdh6ej2 Company 18
h9bsdsf4-8852-6iw-qovigp-99ci5veu1o Company 19
88x0yjwo-8xci-7cu-m0kleg-ly0tcocpp6 Company 20
```

**The desired output form would be just:**

DISTINCT account_id & company_name

Comment: Check out `DISTINCT ON`.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: @jarlh I've had a try with that and it does seem like a useful function, but it seems (unless I'm mistaken) I would have to include the timestamp in the SELECT statement for that to work, which I would ideally avoid.

Comment: where would I provide the sample data? paste it into the question?

Comment: Yes, edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (tbl1.account_id) tbl1.account_id, tbl2.company_name, tbl1.timestamp
FROM tbl1 JOIN
     tbl2
     ON tbl2.company_id = SUBSTRING(x) --Substring from tbl1
WHERE tbl1.eventy_type = 'Y'
ORDER BY tbl1.account_id, tbl1.timestamp DESC;
```

Note that there is no `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Hi @gordon-linoff
That is a good solution, but I would ideally not have the timestamp in my SELECT statement so it doesn't show up in the results. That's what's causing the trouble.

Comment: @Alastair . . . You can remove it.  I would find it useful.